# Using vue router for a file system

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

so my idea of this project is to fetch a JSON file with the structure:

```
const files= [
{
 id : 0,
 name : 'Root Folder',
 owner : 'ownerA',
 date : '17-03-2020',
 files : [
  {
    id : 1,
    name : 'Documents',
    owner : 'OwnerA',
    date : '17-03-2020',
    files : [...]
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name : 'Pictures',
    owner : 'OwnerA',
    date : '17-03-2020',
    files: [...]
  }]}]
```

and create a searchable file system with the given data.
But this is where vue-router comes into play, my idea is that the data gets fetched from the API and make it so as you search through the files, the route gets updated, and when you refresh you stay on the same file you were.

I'm not sure if I should be using the fetch-all method and just pushing in every folder that is clicked on, or if I should create all routes from the moment the page is loaded, as this file system can get quite big.
Also the data then should be fetched from the routes and not directly from the JSON, right?

Please keep in mind this is supposed to be done reusing the same component over and over again.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you expect the filesystem to get really big - you should not define all routes upfront but use https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes to add them dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that was the way I ended up doing, is there any way that I can add the routes as children of the previous route, or should I just keep using 'fetch-all' routes every time I create a new one?

Comment: It won't work in VueRouter 3 but will probably work in v4 - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1156